30 A 50 Hz AC current source for impedance measurement
I am trying to design an ac current source. It should output a current of 30 Arms at 50 Hz and have no more than 12 Vrms open circuit voltage. The current is fed into some device under test (DUT) and I want to measure the voltage over the DUT  for determining the resistance. The DUT has a maximum resistance of 50 mΩ. But if the DUT has some errors it could be as well an open circuit, meaning inginite resistance.
The measuring part shouldn't be a problem. Some voltage measurement with an INA isn't something I haven't done before.
The part I am having a problem with is the current source part.
I was thinking about a simple push-pull stage at the output with some beefy transistors, which is controlled by an opamp output in negative feedback configuration (note: the bottom 50 mΩ resistor is setting the current). Something like this (in this example I am using 25 Arms):

The problem I am seeing with this configuration is, that the opamp is outputting about 150 Vrms, which is a lot. Meaning for it's supply, I would have to have a positive and negative rail of at least +-150 Vrms, which seems problematic.
Initially I thought of using a simple LDO architecture and an INA to provide feedback and adapting it to ac, but I couldn't do it in a meaningful way.

Is this the way to go? It doesn't feel like it. Hopefully someone can give me some feedback on the circuit OR point me in a better direction. I have not yet done such a high current ac source, so I may have many blind spots.
I also thought about buying something like this, but I couldn't find anything.

How much precision do you need on the 30A?  no more than $12V_{RMS}$ open circuit but no less than what 1V?   50Hz  how precise? mains frequency? 30A how precise? distortion?

Just change FET  Beta to 20 to 50. The property has a link to compute Beta from your RdsOn spec Vth and Vgs  then export the link and paste  into your question in some text  with the URL icon (chain link)

For NPN, the property is a fixed hFE which is a simple approximation and default Op Amps are 0 Ohms so add 220 to the output ( Zopen loop) Then you need Rb < hFE x Re  with Vb=5.7  or amplify and saturate with Vbe>= 07.V + Ie*rbe/hFE

But you ideas are breaking the laws of physics for these devices. Better go read datasheets and example designs to understand why you cannot drive 120V on Vgs.

You can buy commercial audio rack-mounted power amplifiers for this sort of power level. It's what I did when I wanted a test signal just like yours. Look harder, for kW PAs.

@D.A.S. Thanks for the input. I had another idea: I use an AC voltage source. Then I set the Voltage 12Vrms and the current limit to 30Arms. Then the source should go into current limiting mode and fix the current to 30Arms, right? I never used ac power sources, but something like this should do the trick I guess: Ametekt AST0501_ATE. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Do you need 12V?

@JasenСлаваУкраїні no, it’s just the upper limit for the open circuit voltage.

For anyone interessted, I found a way to throw money at the problem. I bought an AC Power Source and used the over current protection to limit the current.
Thanks for all the people who responded.

take a 30A capable  3V transformer and put a light-bulb  or power resistor in series with the primary (to limit the short circuit current) .
Instead of regulating the current use a current-transformer or a shunt to measure the actual current.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Use some sort of ratio meter to compare the shunt resistor against the DUT.

Hi, thanks for your response so far. Could you provide some more information on how this operates precisely? I don’t have any experience with current transformers. How can I adjust the current flowing through the load with this approach? I’m a bit confused.

That depends on what you want to do with it.

In essence I just want the current through the dut to be 30Arms. I was not aware that I could use a current transformer. Frankly, I wasn’t even aware current transformers were a thing, because I never had any points of contacts. I just wanted to ask for a more detailed version of your answer so I can understand it better.

the picture is a regular voltage transformer,   this might be a solution or might not, you haven answered my questions.

You wrote: „Instead of regulating the current use a current-transformer or a shunt to measure the actual current.“ I don’t understand how this measurement would help. Wouldn’t I still need to somehow set the input voltage? Let’s say I measure 28Arms with the current transformer or shunt, then I would have to set the input voltage accordingly, until I measure the correct current, right? Meaning I would need some kind of programmable sine wave generator.

I still don't know what you're trying to do so I don't know what solutions are practical and what are not.  CT is a possiblity maybe... or maybe an impedance bridge will work better...  there's many ways to skin cats. But first you need to catch the cat.

Then I don’t understand what you want to know from me. I thought the question is pretty straight forward. So please elaborate.

If you want 12VRMS maximum output voltage, that's 17V peak. With a linear circuit as described in the question (ie, MOSFETs) with an optimized gate drive it would need say +/-20V supply. If the load is 50mOhm plus 50mOhm current sense resistor, then voltage on the load will be 0.1 ohm times 30A, so 3V, and the rest of the voltage has to be dropped by the power transistors. This corresponds to a dissipation of about 500W average in the transistors.
So a linear solution will need to use several MOSFETs in parallel (say 6 pairs) and a good chunk of metal, plus a large heat sink and fan if it intended for continuous use.
What I'd do instead:
First, I'd use a voltage output amp. Current output amps are a can of worms, difficult to compensate and keep stable, because the load inevitably has some inductance (wires... or worse it's a coil) which adds a zero to the response, so you need a custom compensation network to keep it stable. Combining a current source and an inductive load always needs some care.
Then, I would connect that voltage source directly to the load and current measurement resistor, and simply ramp up the amplitude until the target current is reached.
As the 30 amps signal source, a class D amp, for example based as IRS2092S. This chip does not operate in bridged mode, which is what you need in this case. It needs adequate support components. A ready made alternative is a used class D amp rated for 1kW/1Ohm like Behringer iNuke.
Note if you can use a more civilized current like 1A, then the problem becomes much simpler. You can use a chip power opamp like LM1875 to drive it, and measure the current with a current sense amp. The signal will be 30x smaller, but you can just add more gain. It will be noisier, but you can average the measurement over several periods.

Perhaps you don't need to have perfect current control as long as you can accurately measure the current?
In that case, just about any professional audio amplifier will do. You can get them as a rackmount module. They will output 30A happily, with compliance voltage much higher than 12V.
You'll need to set the signal amplitude low enough not to overstress the load. Otherwise it should work well. Beefy pro audio amplifiers are IMHO under-appreciated creatures. One belongs on every bench if you ask me. They can be used for so many things.

Sadly the current needs to be precise.

12/30= 400 mohm load. The driver ought to be same or less than a 50 mV current sensor of 1.5 mohm. These values are your choice.
The typical linear amplifier uses cascaded current gain of emitter followers.
With a 10k Zin and a 3 mohm output impedance requires a current gain of 3.3 e6.  How you achieve that depends on choices of high hFE drivers with some reduction from feedback of excess voltage gain to reduce Zout.
Alternative design uses a current control Buck regulator.
